# Compile errors with JDK 9 - 167

Tags: compiler-errors, java-9

I just downloaded jdk9 build 167 and wanted to continue to check out the new module system. I did so already with a previous build (can't remember exactly which one). Now I installed the 167 and deleted the old JDK.
When I try to compile now I get the error:

error: file should be on source path, or on patch path for module

If I remove the module-info.java (being in the root src path) it compiles fine.
Anyone else having trouble here or did I miss something in the release notes ?

Comment: Please add some more information. Are you compiling on command line? What is that command? What is the project's structure? Is that the full error message?

Comment: I used gradle and I also used IntelliJ IDEA(2017.1.2). The project structure is simple. One source directory /src/main/java. No packages. One Hello World Main Class directly in the root package, so is the module-info.java. The error message is exactly as described as above. Only the java files are given as text before. Interestingly if module-info.java is present. Both Main.java and module-info.java are regarded erroneous. If I remove module-info.java, the Main class compiles and runs without problem.

Comment: Found a jdk 9 166 for X86 somewhere. Same code running like a charm

Comment: Had to put the Main class into a package in order to work.. After that change a try with 167 => same error

Comment: Related to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43722565/2525313)?

Answer (score 2):

You should try IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2 EAP 172.2103.15 from May 12, 2017, see:
https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/.
You can Update from IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.2 to IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2 EAP by selecting "Updates for: Early Access Program".

Comment: Thank you. I addressed JetBrains and they gave me the info that they will have to change a few things in order to work. I did my techno checkouts with the 166. After all the hype about jigsaw not being accepted as is by the JCP I consider postponing my evaluations a bit :-)