# Can't compile a java 9 project in IntelliJ IDEA with module-info

Tags: intellij-idea, java-9

Can't compile a java 9 project in IntelliJ IDEA with module-info.

1. Create a project
2. Add module
3. Create a class with with a main (without module-info.java it runs)
4. Add Module-info.java
5. Run Main ***Fails***

**Configuration**

[image]

**Module-info**

`module httpexample {
}`

**Error**

[image]

Error:(1, 1) java: file should be on source path, or on patch path for module

**Intellij Version**

`IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.2
Build #IU-171.4249.39, built on April 25, 2017
JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-736-b16 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Mac OS X 10.11.1`

Comment: in the module file, try including an export to the class (http.exaple.hello)

Comment: Related to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43705214/2525313)?

Answer (score 8):

It appears to be a new issue caused by Java 9 update 166, I've reported it in YouTrack, please follow for updates:

- [IDEA-172212](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-172212) Compile Error under JDK9-167

Answer (score 1):

I am using IntelliJ EAP 2017.2 build 1909.2 and this is not an issue anymore

Answer (score 0):

I have installed IntelliJ 2017.2 EAP and JDK 9 build 169 and opened my module system projects and it works fine, now my system info is:

IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2 EAP
Build #IU-172.2103.15, built on May 12, 2017
IntelliJ IDEA EAP User
Expiration date: June 11, 2017
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-845-b3 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Mac OS X 10.12.4

[image]