# got issue "file should be on source path, or on patch path for module" in JDK 9 using NetBeans IDE

Tags: java, netbeans

I created a module java project which is very simple. the project hierarchy is as below:
[project hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Euk0Y.jpg)

and the Welcome.java has the code:

```
package com.jdojo.intro;

public class Welcome {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Module System.");
        // Print the module name of the Welcome class
        Class<Welcome> cls = Welcome.class;
        Module mod = cls.getModule();
        String moduleName = mod.getName();
        System.out.format("Module Name: %s%n", moduleName);
    }
}
```

and build the project, got the below error:

```
ant -f C:\\Java9Revealed\\com.jdojo.intro -Dnb.internal.action.name=build jar
init:
Deleting: C:\Java9Revealed\com.jdojo.intro\build\built-jar.properties
deps-jar:
Updating property file: C:\Java9Revealed\com.jdojo.intro\build\built-jar.properties
Compiling 2 source files to C:\Java9Revealed\com.jdojo.intro\build\classes
C:\Java9Revealed\com.jdojo.intro\src\com\jdojo\intro\Welcome.java:1: error: file should be on source path, or on patch path for module
package com.jdojo.intro;
C:\Java9Revealed\com.jdojo.intro\src\module-info.java:1: error: file should be on source path, or on patch path for module
module com.jdojo.intro {
2 errors
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)
```

very appreciated if anyone help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43705214/compile-errors-with-jdk-9-167

Answer (score 1):

So, I got the same error.
Here's how I "solved" it (workaround, kludge, hack)

Go to your project.properties file (location: nbproject/project.properties)
and enter the following:

```
module.name=*name-of-module*
```

so, let's say your *module-info.java* looks like this (based on OP):

```
module com.jdojo.intro
{

}
```

you would modify project.properties ->

```
module.name=com.jdojo.intro
```

and you should be able to build, run unit tests, etc.

The Netbeans support for JDK9 is pretty rough at the moment